# How do I fix the CSS code so that it works with my HTML?

Tags: html, css

The code below has issues.
The CSS code for the menu bar does not seem to be working along with the HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body class="news">
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}
 
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
 
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
 
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}
 
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
 
  /* Option 1 - Display Inline */
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
 
  /* Options 2 - Float
  .nav li {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  */
}</style>
    </head>
   <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="tutorials"><a class="active" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="#">Media</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not understand why the code does not work.

Comment: What do you want to achive? Please rewrite your question and state your problem clearly.

Comment: It's certainly not *helping* that your `<head>` tag is inside the `<body>` tag. Everything from `<head>` to `</head>` should come *before*  `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct code which you need...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}
 
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
 
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
 
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}
 
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
 
  /* Option 1 - Display Inline */
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
 
  /* Options 2 - Float
  .nav li {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body class="news">
  <head>
    </head>
   <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="tutorials"><a class="active" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="#">Media</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```